# c++ platforms solving with dynamic programming

Tags: c++

I Tried to solve this < https://www.e-olymp.com/en/problems/798 > but my code (https://pastebin.com/TGp02qLh )  gave 20% . Can somebody tell me what is my mistake ?

Comment: Provide your code and clear information what you want to know

Comment: i provided my code but sth went wrong and it didn't appear can u see it now?

Comment: Your solution is very poorly formatted, hard to read. But I've taken a glance on it, it seems that you're doing some overkilling actions. Just make it simple. dp[0] = 0, then dp[i] = max(dp[i - 1] + abs(v[i] - v[i - 1]), dp[i - 2] + 3 * abs(v[i] - v[i - 2]))

Comment: actually i wanted to ask how to get the path (I can find the minimum cost but i cant get the path )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### **To restore path:**

Store additional n-sized array, say, `prev[n]`, `prev[0]=-1`. If your dp decides for i'th step that you came from i-1, (i.e. dp[i - 1] + abs(v[i] - v[i - 1]) was larger than dp[i - 2] + 3 * abs(v[i] - v[i - 2])), then `prev[i]=i - 1`, otherwise `prev[i]=i - 2`. Then starting from n-1'th element (assuming that your numeration starts from 0), build the path using `prev`.

### Code snippet:

```
int v = n - 1;
while(v != -1) {
    path.push_back(v + 1);
    v = prev[v];
}
std::reverse(path.begin(), path.end());
```

Comment: Thank u very much